# How do I calculate a position in front of a quaternion given the initial position and the quaternion?

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations, quaternions

Well I want to determine the position in front of, lets say 'an object'.

'An objects' has a position (pX,pY,pZ) and a quaternion rotation (qX,qY,qZ,qW) (where qW seems always to be `0` - because this is from a game I want to modify, I never saw it become `1`)

Now I would like to determine the position at `n` units in front of the position of the object according to the quaternion rotation. How would I do that?

Extra Info:

I know the quaternion combinations produce (when starting to transform from `(1,0,0,0)` if that matters):

`(1,0,0,0)` left side facing north

`(-1,0,0,0)` right side facing north

`(0,-1,0,0)` back facing north

`(0,1,0,0)` front facing north

`(0,0,1,0)` front facing the sky

`(0,0,-1,0)` front facing the ground

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear with your question.  Are each of the $X,Y,Z$ the same?  What does "in front" mean?  Are you determining this after the rotation?

Comment: if you mean position and quaternon, no, I edited the question to use "pX" and "qX". and as for the front, I know the quaternion combination (1,0,0,0) makes the object face it's front to the north and roof to the sky (up); (-1,0,0,0) makes the back face the north, while the object is still upwards.

Comment: sorry I mistaked the rotations, edited them accordingly in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the quaternion into a rotation matrix, using the formula on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

The rows of this matrix are the vectors to which the original coordinate axes are transformed by the rotation.

So, let's suppose your "object" is a rocket, and, in its original position, its nose points along the $z$-axis. Then, after transformation by the quaternion $(w,x,y,z)$, the formula on the wikipedia page tells us that its nose points in the direction of the vector $v = (2xz -2yw, 2yz+2xw, 1 - 2x^2 - 2y^2)$.
Then, a position $n$ units in front of the rocket is $p + n*v$, where $p = (pX, pY, pZ)$.

The [GeometricTools site](http://www.geometrictools.com) has good code for working with quaternions and rotations. Documentation is [here](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/Quaternions.pdf), and code is [here](http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Algebra/Algebra.html).